# java - automatically printing stack traces for uncaught exceptions

Tags: java

Is there a way to have java print a stack trace to console for all uncaught exceptions like in many IDEs, other than overwriting the uncaught exception handler in the thread/threadgroup?

Comment: That is the default behaviour....

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand your question. What you describe is already the default behavior of most if not all JVMs: a thread that gets hit by an uncaught exception will print the stack trace and exit. If you want it to do something different, then the uncaught exception handler is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like:

```
catch(MyException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw e;
}
```

?